# Angular Material. md-is-locked-open is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm designing a simple user interface in Angular Material for a web application, but I have the following problem with the `<md-sidenav>` directive:
The `md-is-locked-open` attribute seems not to be working. I tried to set it to false, but the sidenav is anyway displayed, I tried to set it using `$mdMedia` service, but the sidenav is not hidden on smaller screens. How can I make it work? My HTML below:

```
<body ng-app="test" layout="column">

    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="center">
        <p>EASYRASH</p>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-6dp" md-component-id="left">
        </md-sidenav>
    </div>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
var app = angular.module("test", ['ngMaterial']);
```

Comment: For me it seems to be working: https://plnkr.co/edit/peMyZh8pA0Fzz2Kucw7n?p=preview

Comment: @GustavoGabriel In your demo it works, so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. I am executing it in local without server and i'm importing library only with CDN. Can it be a problem?

Comment: Maybe the library you are importing is outdated? Are you using the latest version ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was importing    `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js` 

instead of  

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js`  

Thank you

Comment: Added an answer, can you please accept it ? Glad everything worked out =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the angular material version he was using was outdated. When he updated it everything started working as expected =)